# Upload file with AJAX & PHP - $_FILES array is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have read close to 20 different forum post/stackoverflow questions/answers about this but I just can't get this work. I've worked with jQuery/PHP about 5years now but this is first time when I need to do something like this with AJAX.

So... for now, I'm just testing and trying upload .txt file and try get the contents of it by using `file_get_contents()` and send it back to my JS code.

I have removed all fancy staff and simplified my files as much as I could, so this is my HTML file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form id="uploadForm" action="url/to/php/script">
                <input type="file" name="frame" />
                <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JS

```
$("#uploadForm").bind('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url/to/php/script',
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

and in my PHP script I have `var_dump($_FILES)` which gives me empty array.

My JS & form are copied from one of the stackoverflow's answers. URL: [$_POST and $_FILES empty after AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747572/post-and-files-empty-after-ajax-file-upload) - because it's marked as it works but for me... still empty.

Normally my form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"` but theres no difference.

My jQuery lib: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js`

I came here because I feel like there's no more things I could try, no matter what I do, `$_FILES` array is empty.

Comment: You're using a *very*, ***very*** old version of jQuery. try upgrading it to at least 1.12. Ideally 3.2, if you don't need legacy IE support

Comment: you have to use multipart/formdata as form type

Comment: @Rory McCrossan oh.... my.... god.... I have copied my jquery lib from my previous project but I guess this time I copied it from pretty old project. haha I changed my lib to 1.12 and it works now. Thank you!:)

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you

Comment: @mtizziani jQuery adds that for you when you give `data` a `FormData` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX logic is fine. The issue is because you're using a very, ***very*** outdated version of jQuery, and there have been many tweaks to the AJAX logic over the years of development - especially since the rise in support for `FormData` and sending binary data via AJAX.

You should upgrade jQuery to at least 1.12, ideally 3.2 if you don't need legacy IE support.

Answer (score 0):

```
use new version jquery library like this, your ajax code looks good so for this requirement need to update your jquery library . you use old library in that case it is not working 

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js
```

more for information

https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/php/script",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }           
});
}));
</script>
```